# RewritePatternRule for jetty in karaf (make angular deep links work)

Tags: angular, talend, jetty-9

I've got my little angular app running in a Talend ESB container, powered by (embedded?) jetty:

```
karaf@trun()> web:list
ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath | Name
----+-------------+-------------+-------+-----------------+--------------------------
415 | Active      | Deployed    | 80    | /web-app       | web-app (0.1.0.SNAPSHOT)
```

Which is then perfectly showing up under: `localhost:8040/web-app/`

The problem starts with deep links, like e.g. `localhost:8040/web-app/partner/{id}` - the part `/partner/{id}` is dynamic and handled/routed by angular. So, everything after '/web-app/' should be ignored by jetty.

I tried to configure `etc/jetty.xml` as follows:

```
<New id="Rewrite" class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler">
    <Set name="rewriteRequestURI">true</Set>
    <Set name="rewritePathInfo">false</Set>
    <Set name="originalPathAttribute">requestedPath</Set>

    <Call name="addRule">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule">
          <Set name="pattern">/web-app/*</Set>
          <Set name="replacement">/web-app/</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>

...
```

Tracing shows that the configuration is actually considered:

```
2018-09-26 17:39:47,158 | DEBUG | qtp42050594-114 | RuleContainer | 173 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.3.14.v20161028 | applied org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewritePatternRule[hT][/web-app/*][/web-app/]
2018-09-26 17:39:47,159 | DEBUG | qtp42050594-114 | RuleContainer | 173 - org.eclipse.jetty.util - 9.3.14.v20161028 | rewrote /web-app/partner/123 to /web-app/partner/123
```

Why is it not rewritten to `/web-app/`?
Of course, I'll get a lovely 404:

```
HTTP ERROR 404
Problem accessing /web-app/partner/123. Reason:

    Not Found
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated!